# httpResponse.data is Empty for IAP Receipt Validation with Parse CloudCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to validate an Apple IAP auto-renewing receipt (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html), but the response payload seems to be (surprisingly) empty. I would greatly appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

Here is the javascript implementation via Parse CloudCode:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('validateReceipt', function (request, response) {
  // params:
  // debugMode
  // userObjectId
  // receiptData
  var storeURL = null;
    if (request.params.debugMode) {
        storeURL = 'https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt';
    } else {
        storeURL = 'http://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt';
    }

  var receiptAsBase64EncodedString = request.params.receiptData;
  var postData = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: storeURL,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: { 'receipt-data': receiptAsBase64EncodedString,
              'password': 'SHARED_SECRET' }
  }

  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest(postData).then(function (httpResponse) {
    var expirationDate = httpResponse.data.latest_receipt.expiration_date;
    var userQuery = new Parse.Query('_User');
    userQuery.get(request.params.userObjectId, {
      success: function(user) {
        user.set('subscriptionExpirationDate', expirationDate);
        user.save(null, {
          success: function(thread) {
            return response.success('Subscription Active');
          }, 
          error: function(user, error) {
            console.error('Error saving subscriptionExpirationDate for User: ' + error.code + ' - ' + error.message);
            return response.error('Error saving subscriptionExpirationDate for User: ' + error.code + ' - ' + error.message);
          }
        });
      },
      error: function(object, error) {
        console.error('Error fetching User: ' + error.code + ' - ' + error.message);
        return response.error('Error saving subscriptionExpirationDate for User: ' + error.code + ' - ' + error.message);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

If I print httpResponse.data to the console, the output is:

```
No Message provided
```

However, if I implement the same logic from my client in obj-C, I have the expected result:

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *requestContents = @{
                                  @"receipt-data": [receiptData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0],
                                  @"password": @"SHARED_SECRET"
                                  };
NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestContents
                                                      options:0
                                                        error:&error];

NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"];
NSMutableURLRequest *storeRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:storeURL];
[storeRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[storeRequest setHTTPBody:requestData];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:storeRequest queue:queue
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                           if (!connectionError) {
                               NSError *error;
                               NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
                           }
                       }];
```

Printing jsonReponse:

```
{
    environment = Sandbox;
    "latest_receipt" = "...";
    "latest_receipt_info" =     (
        {
          "expires_date" = "2015-10-09 02:11:19 Etc/GMT";
          [...]
        },
    status = 0;
}
```